# Flutter - Load assets for tests

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Not sure if it's a limitation or something, but below code does not load anything. I have some data driven behaviour that I'd like to test isolated.

class Loader

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class Loader {
  Future<String> load() async{
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/sketch.json');
  }
}
```

The test

```
testWidgets('Should parse load sketch.json', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    var loaderFuture = new Loader();

    Future<String> resultFuture = loaderFuture.load();

    resultFuture.then((value) => print(value))
        .catchError((error) => print(error));

    while(true){};
  });
```

Future does not return neither success nor error and hangs forever. I know 
the **while(true)** locking up the test, but for now I just wanted to see sketch.json printed

Asset location

[image]

Comment: Can you try `rootBundle.loadString('packages/my_app/assets/json/sketch.json');` where `my_app` is from `name: ...` in `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Same result. Nothing gets printed. **name: flutter_generator_demo** and the path was like **return await rootBundle.loadString('packages/flutter_generator_demo/assets/json/sketch.json');** . Important to mention that I can load it when running the app

Comment: I think this is fixed now. Can you try in recent `dev` or `master`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the documentation of [DefaultAssetBundle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultAssetBundle-class.html) it describes using it and a AssetBundle to provide your own assets.

Comment: @Simon - What about testing something other than widgets, I have an API class which need to load a JSON file from the assets folder, its not working in the test environment.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Use rootBundle.loadString('<asset_name>') to read json data as string and map it accordingly.

Comment: @RajYadav can you expand on how I could be defining assets for my tests but not of the application that use my package?

Comment: Link is broken :(

Answer (score 19):

To use `rootBundle` in your tests you need this at the beginning of your test programs:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

...
void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Comment: Thank you, replace `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` with `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` actually works!

Comment: It's not worked for me!
Can you send a sample project that used rootBundle.loadString(key) inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that wraps the rootBundle:

```dart
@injectable
class AssetsManager {
  Future<String> loadString(String path) {
    return rootBundle.loadString(path);
  }
}
```

Then inject it to your class and in your test override its dependency:

```dart
  getIt.unregister<AssetsManager>();
  getIt.registerSingleton<AssetsManager>(AssetsManagerMock());
```

Based on your test scenario, Configure what will be returned when calling **loadString** by using Mocktail's **when** method.

I'm using [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) for DI. Hope it's clear enough.