# Unable to load asset SVG during widget testing

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, testing, svg

I want to do a widget test on some of my screens which includes `SvgPicture` widget, but I can't do it because it throws an exception.

Code to reproduce the error:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';


void main() {
  testWidgets(
    'SvgPicture.asset passes',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: SvgPicture.asset('icons/pencil.svg'),
        ),
      ));
      await tester.pump();
    },
  );
}
```

Result of execution:

```dart
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SVG ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving a single-frame picture stream:
Unable to load asset: icons/pencil.svg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:224:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)
...

Picture provider: ExactAssetPicture(name: "icons/pencil.svg", bundle: null, colorFilter: null)
Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#c2c00(), name: "icons/pencil.svg",
  colorFilter: null)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

How do I pass the test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Upd:** You should follow this answer instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/62666051/9586934

---

Just create fake `AssetBundle` and wrap the whole app with it:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

class FakeAssetBundle extends Fake implements AssetBundle {
  final String svgStr = '''<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10"></svg>''';

  @override
  Future<String> loadString(String key, {bool cache = true}) async => svgStr;
}

void main() {
  testWidgets(
    'SvgPicture.asset passes',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(DefaultAssetBundle(
        bundle: FakeAssetBundle(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: SvgPicture.asset('icons/pencil.svg'),
          ),
        ),
      ));
      await tester.pump();
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: And how should we do this for an integration test where we just run the main() function in the test?

Comment: And I'd like the real assets to display

Comment: How to do the same for PNG?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the proposed solution didn't work for me. I expect it's related to the changes during time period between the posted answer and the newest `flutter_svg` version, which is `2.0.3` today.

Basically, I took a look into [flutter_svg source code](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/blob/master/test/widget_svg_test.dart) to find out how library creators test, and based on that I created working solution:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

const String svgStr = '''<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10"></svg>''';

class FakeAssetBundle extends Fake implements AssetBundle {
  @override
  Future<String> loadString(String key, {bool cache = true}) async {
    return svgStr;
  }

  @override
  Future<ByteData> load(String key) async {
    return Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(svgStr)).buffer.asByteData();
  }
}

void main() {
  testWidgets(
    'SvgPicture.asset passes',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(DefaultAssetBundle(
        bundle: FakeAssetBundle(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: SvgPicture.asset('whatever.svg'),
          ),
        ),
      ));
      await tester.pump();
    },
  );
}
```

Disclaimer: it's not a full test, but only the troublesome part what was pointed out in the question.

Answer (score 0):

My example explains this Docs: [DefaultAssetBundle class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultAssetBundle-class.html) in more detail.

1. Store Svg images as String:

```js
class SvgData {
  static const String redSquare =
      '''<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
           <path d="m0,0h1v1H0" fill="#F00"/>
          </svg>''';
}
```

2. Create your own **bundle**:

```js
class SvgAssetBundle extends CachingAssetBundle {
ByteData getByteSvg(String svgData) {
  return ByteData.view(
    Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(svgData)).buffer,
  );
}

@override
Future<ByteData> load(String key) async {
  switch (key) {
    /// Define a key to get the Svg image in here.
    case 'redSquare':
      {
        return getByteSvg(SvgData.redSquare);
      }

    default:
      {
        return ByteData(0);
      }
  }
}
}
```

3. Provide an instance of the **bundle** to the Material App:

```js
/// ... some code ...
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  /// Wrap [MaterialApp] with [DefaultAssetBundle].  
  return DefaultAssetBundle(
    /// Provide your bundle.
    bundle: SvgAssetBundle(),
    child: const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    ),
  );
}
/// ... some code ...
```

4. Add an Svg image to your code.

```js
/// ... some code ...
/// Get access to the instance of the bundle.
AssetBundle bundle = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context);

/// ... some code ...
child: Center(
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          /// Use a key that you defined in [SvgAssetBundle]
          'redSquare',
          /// Provide your bundle here.
          bundle: bundle,
        ),
      ),
/// ... some code ...
```

5. Test file remains as usual.

```js
import 'package:your_app_name/main.dart' as app;

/// ... some code ...
/// Don't forget to add for Integration Test.
IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

group(
  'end-to-end test',
      () {
    testWidgets(
      'test action description',
          (WidgetTester tester) async {
        
        /// Call the main function as usual. 
        app.main();

      },
    );
  },
);
```